# BlueImp File Upload Widget for Yii2 Not working

Tags: jquery, file-upload, yii2

Hello i am working with [BlueImp File Upload Widget for Yii2](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget) in yii2. It is able to **Add** file but when i click on **start** for file upload getting **Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**. How can i solve this.

Comment: Just a question, yuo want to upload a JSON File?

Comment: Thanks  scaisEdge for reply but i am uploading image file, though i am getting above error.

Comment: The error is tipical of a JSON file non properly formatted eg with or without the comma separator in the wrong place and I guess there is a JSON file in som part of your application

Comment: But i am returning html result not json how can i solve that.

Comment: @Akbari piyush I had the same problem. I resolved by placing an action for upload and another to show the upload input.